# How to play a video on Cordova 3.4.0 - Android

Tags: android, html, cordova, video

I'm trying to play a mp4 video on my app with HTML5 `video tag`. I tried differents source path but no one is working. A flash alternative doesn't work either.

```
 <video>
     <source src="videos/video.mp4" type="video/mp4"></source>
     <!-- <source src="file:///android_asset/www/videos/video.mp4" type="video/mp4"></source> -->
 </video>
```

I tried [this plugin](https://github.com/jaeger25/Html5Video) but the path generated (`android.resource://com.example.myapp/videoId`) throws an error in the console : `net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME`

My tests are done on Android `4.4.3`.

How to play a video ?

Comment: +1 were you able to find a solution for this